# Pipelines security groups Azure DevOps API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to see which group/users have access and what are the permissions to specific pipeline in a project with REST API?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is not a rest api that can directly check group/users's permissions to a specific pipeline. You have to use multiple rest apis to get what you want. See below steps;

1, Get the Groups via [Groups list API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). Get all Users via [Users list API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

You need to get the `subject descriptor` of the group/user from the result.

eg. `"descriptor: "acs.Nzc4OWYwOWQtZTA1My00ZjJlLWJkZWUtMGM4Zjg0NzZhNGJj"`

2, Use the subject descriptor from above rest api to get the `identity descriptor` via [Identities - Read Identities](http://Identities%20-%20Read%20Identities) rest api

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?subjectDescriptors={subjectDescriptors}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

Get `identity descriptor` from the Result:

eg. `"descriptor": "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;7a394543-62fd-4274-a7d2-8fac775942b6\\jtseng@vscsi.us"`

3, Use [Access Control Lists - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest api to check the permissions for this group/user using above `identity descriptor` and token

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?token={token}&descriptors={descriptors}&includeExtendedInfo={includeExtendedInfo}&recurse={recurse}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

The securityNamespaceId of Build is a constant value `33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/manage-tokens-namespaces?view=azure-devops#example-list-local-security-namespaces) for all securityNamespaceIds.

The token's format is `projectId/buildDefinitionId`

For example the request url to get the permissions for a buildDefinition can be like below:

```
"https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/_apis/accesscontrollists/33344d9c-fc72-4d6f-aba5-fa317101a7e9?includeExtendedInfo=True&token=****-****-4fa8-b2f1-0ee8f4fc82c5/87&descriptors=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;bfbbe64a-653b-47f8-8f74-a56680a9bc6a:Build:39e13f04-cb4e-4fa8-b2f1-0ee8f4fc82c5&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
```

Then you will get the permission result from the `extendedInfo` like below:

[image]

In order to understand the permission value (eg. `3` in below ) in `extendedInfo`

```
extendedInfo":  {"effectiveAllow":  3}
```

You can check the [Security Namespaces - Query rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security%20namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). See below name of the permission and its bit for Build Security Namespaces.

```
  bit name                           displayName                           namespaceId                         
  --- ----                           -----------                           -----------                         
    1 ViewBuilds                     View builds                           00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    2 EditBuildQuality               Edit build quality                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    4 RetainIndefinitely             Retain indefinitely                   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    8 DeleteBuilds                   Delete builds                         00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   16 ManageBuildQualities           Manage build qualities                00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   32 DestroyBuilds                  Destroy builds                        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   64 UpdateBuildInformation         Update build information              00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  128 QueueBuilds                    Queue builds                          00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  256 ManageBuildQueue               Manage build queue                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  512 StopBuilds                     Stop builds                           00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 1024 ViewBuildDefinition            View build pipeline                   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 2048 EditBuildDefinition            Edit build pipeline                   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 4096 DeleteBuildDefinition          Delete build pipeline                 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 8192 OverrideBuildCheckInValidation Override check-in validation by build 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
16384 AdministerBuildPermissions     Administer build permissions          00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

The value of the `effectiveAllow` is the sum of the bits for the allowed permissions. In above example. the effectiveAllow is `3`. So the permissions for this group is `ViewBuilds -->allow` and  `EditBuildQuality-->allow`

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm going to try this way :)

Comment: Hi @Baequiraheal Did you get a chance to try above solution? How did it go?

Comment: I figured out it can be done with multiple hierarchy queries. I can post the solution later tomorrow if it can be usefull for someone :) It was going to be complicated to sum the bits and figure out what are the exact premissions.

Comment: Hi @Baequiraheal. It would be great if you could share your solution. Thanks!